# SELECT MAX() FROM TABLE using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, having

I have some table:

```
name    dep_id  salary
Vasia   5       1000
Oleg    5       1300
Vitia   4       1000
Sacha   3       1100
Kolia   5       1600
Lesha   2       1400
Sergey  4       1200
Marina  5       1300
Olga    5       1500
Igor    4       1400
Valia   3       1500
Erema   4       1500
```

I need to get the `name` of the employees with the maximum `salary` in his department

i.e I need

```
 Lesha   1400
 Valia   1500
 Erema   1500
 Kolia   1600
```

I tried:

```
SELECT name, max(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY dep_id
```

but this displays incorrect values

how can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
select e1.*
from employees e1
join
(
  SELECT dep_id, max(salary) as msal
  FROM employees
  GROUP BY dep_id
) e2 on e1.dep_id = e2.dep_id
    and e1.salary = e2.msal
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.name,t2.sallary
from Employees t1 join
     (select dep_id,MAX(Sallary) as Sallary
      from Employees
      group by dep_id) t2 on t1.dep_id=t2.dep_id and t1.sallary=t2.sallary
order by t2.sallary
```

Result:

```
name    Sallary
---------------
Lesha   1400
Valia   1500
Erema   1500
Kolia   1600
```

Demo in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f18c0/5)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query for the required output :

```
    select name,sallary from employees t1 where (dep_id,sallary) in
    (select dep_id,max(sallary) from employees group by dep_id);
```